# nginx 408 errors with centos 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, centos, unicorn, centos6

We have a loadbalancer setup with a couple of centos boxes behind it running nginx/unicorn/rails.

I noticed that we only see 408 errors on the centos6 boxes while the centos5 servers are fine. the nginx and /proc configuration is the same on all machines.

I am aware that those connections are created by modern browsers. I just wanna find out why we get those 408er on centos6 only. Any ideas?

```
23.135.172.241 - - [27/Aug/2012:13:45:21 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-" foo.bar.com 50.me.ip11:443 60.000 -
23.135.172.241 - - [27/Aug/2012:13:45:21 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-" foo.bar.com 50.me.ip12:443 60.000 -
15.144.213.171 - - [27/Aug/2012:13:45:21 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-" foo.bar.com 50.me.ip11:443 60.000 -
19.195.246.143 - - [27/Aug/2012:13:45:21 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-" foo.bar.com 50.me.ip12:443 60.000 -
19.195.246.143 - - [27/Aug/2012:13:45:21 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-" foo.bar.com 50.me.ip11:443 60.002 -
3.228.140.241 - - [27/Aug/2012:13:45:21 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-" foo.bar.com 50.me.ip39:443 60.000 -
15.60.229.52 - - [27/Aug/2012:13:45:21 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-" foo.bar.com 50.me.ip39:443 60.000 -
7.48.175.3 - - [27/Aug/2012:13:45:22 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-" foo.bar.com 50.me.ip37:443 60.000 -
2.160.154.89 - - [27/Aug/2012:13:45:22 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-" foo.bar.com 50.me.ip12:443 60.000 -
4.104.120.184 - - [27/Aug/2012:13:45:22 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-" foo.bar.com 50.me.ip12:443 60.000 -
11.1.52.25 - - [27/Aug/2012:13:45:22 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-" foo.bar.com 50.me.ip39:443 60.000 -
16.81.34.95 - - [27/Aug/2012:13:45:22 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-" foo.bar.com 50.me.ip12:443 60.000 -
19.200.6.58 - - [27/Aug/2012:13:45:22 +0000] "-" 408 0 "-" "-" foo.bar.com 50.me.ip37:443 60.000 -
```

Comment: you should post on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: can you paste your nginx config here?